# Algorithm to construct Balanced Incomplete Block Design (BIBD) combinations

Tags: algorithm, combinations, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

I need some reference/help with the algorithm to develop all possible combinations as per the Balanced Incomplete Block Design (BIBD).

To be more specific, I want to generate maximum possible combinations in which total players(M) can be grouped in teams of size N such that no two players fall in the same team more than two times. - e.g. -

`Input:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,] - Here each number denotes player and M=6`

`Output: {1.2.3, 1.4.5, 1.2.6, 6.3.5, 2.4.3, 5.6.2, 1.4.6, 5.2.4, 4.3.6, 1.3.5} - Here N=3`

The output above is the maximum possible combinations we can group 6 players in teams (each team of size 3 in this case) and also satisfy the condition that no two players fall in the same team more than two times.

**Current Progress:**

I was able to compute all the combinations possible and then filter out these combinations as per my condition(same players at max 2 times) using brute-force approach. In this way I am able to arrive at some combinations but the result in not optimal. I need to maximize it.
For the example above, I was able to generate the following pairs -

`{1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.3.4, 2.3.4, 1.5.6, 2.5.6}`

Though all these combinations are valid but they are not maximum possible combinations.

If you want my current code by which I am generating above pairs, will be happy to share.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately BIBD construction is highly parameter specific.

Comment: Have you read this paper? https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/s13428-019-01326-x.pdf